# What is the difference between opening an application from terminal Vs directly opening it?

Tags: terminal, process, cpu

I could open Firefox browser either by clicking FF icon on desktop or by running `~/firefox/firefox &` in the terminal. What are the differences in these two ways of running? I am wondering because in `System Monitor` bash is showing 100 % CPU usage and I have opened Firefox from a tab in a terminal. Could there be a connection between these two? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Either way you are creating a firefox process to run in the background through a shell.

Firefox is quite bloated now a-days. Depending on your hardware and version of firefox, it would not be surprising if you run at 100% usage often.

Per cas: You can greatly improve CPU utilization in Firefox by installing NoScript and AdBlock and similar plugins so it isn't wasting CPU on spyware and ads. Only enable scripting on sites that a) really need it and b) are useful enough to you that it's worth it.

Comment: You can greatly improve CPU utilisation in Firefox by installing NoScript and AdBlock and similar plugins so it isn't wasting CPU on spyware and ads.  Only enable scripting on sites that a) really need it and b) are useful enough to you that it's worth it.

Comment: @cas: This is a good point, I will add it to the answer. Thank you, cas.